# How to integrate my dictionary codes with my Word and Line Concordance Application?

Tags: python, dictionary, data-structures

I have implemented **Word and Line Concordance Application** whose code is here:

```
import re
from collections import defaultdict
def concordance():
    wordConcordanceDict = defaultdict(list)

    with open('stop_words_small.txt') as sw:
        words = (line.strip() for line in sw)
        stop_words = set(words)

    with open('small_file.txt') as f:
        for line_number, line in enumerate(f, 1):
            words = (re.sub(r'[^\w\s]','',word).lower() for word in line.split())
            good_words = (word for word in words if word not in stop_words)
            for word in good_words:
                wordConcordanceDict[word].append(line_number)

    for word in sorted(wordConcordanceDict):
        print('{}: {}'.format(word, ' '.join(map(str, wordConcordanceDict[word]))))
concordance()
```

Now I don't know how to combine my dictionary code with the above program of word concordance.
Here is my dictionary code which I want to combine with the above program and time it.

```
from entry Import Entry
from unordered_linked_list import UnorderedList

class ChainingDict(object):
    """Dictionary implemented using hashing with chaining."""

    def __init__(self, capacity = 8):
        self._capacity = capacity
        self._table = []
        for index in range(self._capacity):
            self._table.append(UnorderedList())
        self._size = 0
        self._index = None

    def __contains__(self, key):
        """Returns True if key is in the dictionary or
        False otherwise."""
        self._index = abs(hash(key)) % self._capacity
        entry = Entry(key, None)
        
        return self._table[self._index].search(entry)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        """Returns the value associated with key or
        returns None if key does not exist."""
        if key in self:
            entry = Entry(key, None)
            entry = self._table[self._index].remove(entry)
            self._table[self._index].add(entry)
            return entry.getValue()
        else:
            return None 

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        """Removes the entry associated with key."""
        entry = Entry(key, None)
        if key in self:
            entry = Entry(key, None)
            entry = self._table[self._index].remove(entry)
            self._size -= 1

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        """Inserts an entry with key/value if key
        does not exist or replaces the existing value
        with value if key exists."""
        entry = Entry(key, value)
        if key in self:
            entry = self._table[self._index].remove(entry)
            entry.setValue(value)
        else:
            self._size += 1
        self._table[self._index].add(entry)

    def __len__(self):
        return self._size

    def __str__(self):
        result = "HashDict: capacity = " +  \
                 str(self._capacity) + ", load factor = " + \
                 str(len(self) / self._capacity) 
        for i in range(self._capacity):
            result += "\nRow " + str(i) + ": " + str(self._table[i])
        return result

    def __iter__(self):
        """Iterates over the keys of the dictionary"""
        # ADD CODE HERE<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        pass
 
def main():
    d = ChainingDict(3)
    d["Name"] = "Bob"
    d["Age"] = 26
    d["Color"] = "red"
    print("Items from iterator:")
    for item in d:
        print(item)
    print( d)
    print( "Expect True:", "Name" in d)
    print( "Expect Bob:", d["Name"])
    print( "Expect None:", d["Address"])
    d["Age"] = 27
    print( "Expect 27:", d["Age"])
    del d["Name"]
    del d["Address"]
    print (d)
    print("Items from iterator:")
    for item in d:
        print(item)
    return d

if __name__ == "__main__": d = main()
```

**Please let me know how to combine my ChainingDict with my Word Concordance Program and also mention how can I time it.**